# How do I put each record inputted by a user within a loop in a text file

Tags: python

So, I have my code which is for a user wanting to loan books from a library or somewhere. They input the code for the book that they'd like to loan, I have the code with the assigned name, price etc in a text file. They input the quantity of the book that they'd like to loan then a price is calculated. If they want to loan more books, the code loops back and they can repeat the process. I want to make a separate receipt file, which stores everything that the user enters within the loop in this receipt file, and then adds everything together. I read some stuff and tried this, but there is an error and I don't know what I did wrong. Here is my code:

```
task=input("Enter 'b' to borrow a book, press 'x' to exit. \n")
if task.lower()== "b":
    myfile=open("books.txt", "r+") 
    details=myfile.readlines() 
    while True:
        book=input("Enter the 8 digit book code. \n")
        while len(book) !=8 
            print("Your code is not 8 digits long, please try again.\n") 

        f = open("books.txt", "r+") 
        for line in f.readlines():
            quantity=input("How many copies of the book do you wish to purchase?\n")
            t = line.split(" ")
            price = float(t[3])
            code = t[1]
            NameOfBook = t[2]
            total=(price)* int(quantity)
            with open("receipt.txt", "w") as receiptFile:
            receiptFile.write(str(code))
            receiptFile.write(float(NameOfItem))
            receiptFile.write(int(quantity))
            receiptFile.write(str(price))
            receiptFile.write(str(total))
        break
    answer = input("Do you want to loan another book? Enter 'yes' if you would like to. ")
    if answer == "yes":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

What I tried to enter is this:

```
with open("receipt.txt", "w") as receiptFile:
receiptFile.write(str(code))
receiptFile.write(float(NameOfBook))
receiptFile.write(int(quantity))
receiptFile.write(str(price))
receiptFile.write(str(total))
```

I assumed that it would open the file that I made named receipt.txt and then write in each thing the user inputs, however I ended with no success. This came up instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PYTHOn\New python edited for loop.py", line 19, in <module>
    receiptFile.write(float(NameOfBook))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Narnia,'
```

Please help if possible. thanks :)

Comment: Please tell use what error you got, showing the whole traceback message is really helpful for us to help you :)

Comment: Done!!             ................

Comment: receiptFile.write(float(NameOfItem)) `NameOfItem` is 'Narnia,'

Comment: ok, now tell my why you do `float(NameOfBook)`, it literally means "convert `NameOfBook` to a floating point number".... convert the name to a number?

Comment: also since you are writing to a text file you will only be able to write strings to it, so `.write(int(quantity))` will raise an error like `TypeError: string argument expected, got 'int'` and similarly for the `float`

Comment: Thanks! So what do I do if I want to add in numbers?